# Error message when installing Ruby DevKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devkit

I've installed Ruby 2.0 with a Windows Ruby Installer (rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p481-x64), unpacked DevKit (DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx) on a folder without spaces
but when i run ruby dk.rb init i got that message ???

```
C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb init

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:172:in 'find': unknown encoding name - CP720 (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:172:in 'initialize'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:231:in 'exception'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:231:in 'raise'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:231:in 'check'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:254:in 'OpenKey'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:385:in 'open'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb:496:in 'open'
    from dk.rb:116:in 'block in scan_for'
    from dk.rb:114:in 'each'
    from dk.rb:114:in 'scan_for'
    from dk.rb:136:in 'block in installed_rubies'
    from dk.rb:136:in 'collect'
    from dk.rb:136:in 'installed_rubies'
    from dk.rb:144:in 'init'
    from dk.rb:311:in 'run'
    from dk.rb:330:in '<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    C:\DevKit> chcp 1252
    C:\DevKit> ruby dk.rb init
```